# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, import

I am trying to import a JSON file and convert it into a dataframe to be used for data analysis in Python. Below is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('Kickstarter_2015-06-12.json','r',encoding = "utf8") as f:
  data5 = json.loads(f.read())
 df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data5, record_path =['projects'])
```

However, I got this error when I run these codes:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

May I know how do I solve this problem? Any help in this area would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample of the file. Also, try `json.load(f)` instead of `json.loads(f.read())`, although this is unlikely to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use this [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/) to make sure that your JSON is properly formatted, it seems that you're missing a comma somewhere.

It could also happen when " or ' are involved in your strings/values because these characters can mess up the parser but it's hard to tell without seeing the JSON itself. If json shows as valid in json lint and you can find the values that contain special characters please provide a small example without having to expose your entire json.